# How to achieve cartesian product joins in strict mode in Hive?

Tags: hive, cartesian

As you know in strict mode, Hive does not allow cartesian product joins, but can we achieve it in another way in that mode?

Answer (score -2):

In strict mode, Cartesian product is not allowed. So, You have to have includes JOIN Condition in ON Clause instead of WHERE clause like this:

```
hive> SELECT * FROM fracture_act JOIN fracture_ads > WHERE fracture_act.planner_id = fracture_ads.planner_id;
FAILED: Error in semantic analysis:
In strict mode, cartesian product is not allowed. If you really want to perform the operation,
+set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict+
```

Here is a properly constructed query with JOIN and ON clauses:

```
hive> SELECT * FROM fracture_act JOIN fracture_ads > ON (fracture_act.planner_id = fracture_ads.planner_id);
```

... normal results ...

Comment: Can you please see my detail description of my question here                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889743/how-to-achieve-the-result-of-cartesian-product-by-not-using-the-cross-join-in-st